# Is it possible to limit to size of a List in Reads

Tags: playframework-2.6

My controller receives a `json`. One of the elements in the `json` is an array of strings. I have written the following `validation` for the `json`

```
  implicit val pQ:Reads[PQ] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "h").read[List[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "i").read[List[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "s").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "t").read[Set[String]] and
    )(PQ.apply _)
```

Is it possible to write a `Reads` or `Validate` such that the `json` gets rejected if the size of a List is more than a specified value (say the size of `i` list should not be more than 3?

Answer (score 0):

I might write another answer where the code is more functional and organised. Happy to accept other answers as well.

The way to customize validating `json` is to extend `Reads` trait and implement its `reads` method.

`abstract def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A]`

I want to achieve two things
1) validate the the json has all the required fields
2) ensure that some of the fields have max-size limit (eg. no. of images which could be sent).

Json validation works by calling `validate` or `validateOpt` method of `JsValue`. These methods expect an implicit `Reads` and pass the `JsValue` to it.

`def validate[T](implicit rds: Reads[T]): JsResult[T] = rds.reads(this)`

So to validate json and map it to my `PQ` class, I had to create a `Reads[PQ]`. But because I want validation beyond just the structure of the `json`, I have to extends `Reads` and implement my own `reads`.

To do step 1, I created `Reads[PQ]` the normal way (just checking that all the required fields are present and can map to my `PQ` class

```
implicit val pQStructurallyCorrect:Reads[PQ] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and
    (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "h").read[List[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "i").read[List[String]] and
      (JsPath \ "s").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "t").read[Set[String]] and
    )(PQ.apply _)
```

To add step 2, I created another `Reads[PQ]` by extending `Read[PQ]` and by overriding the `reads`

```
implicit object PQReads extends Reads[PQ] {
    def reads(json:JsValue):JsResult[PQ]  =  {
//check that the structure of the json is correct by utilizing the Reads created for step 1
      val structurallyValidated = json.validateOpt[PQ](pQStructurallyCorrect) 
      structurallyValidated match {
        case JsSuccess(pQOpt,path)=>{ //structure is correct. now check content
          val result = pQOpt.map(pq=>{
            if(pq.image.length <0 || pq.image.length > 3)
            {
              JsError("invalid no. of images")
            }
            else {
              JsSuccess(pq)
            }
          }).getOrElse(JsError("Error in validating Json"))
          result
        }
        case JsError(errors) =>{
          JsError(errors)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now to validate the json, I use `PQReads` object

```
implicit val qReads:Reads[Q] = (JsPath \ "p-q").read[PQ](PQReads)
    .map((x:PQ)=>Q.apply (x))
```

What is happening above is when my application receives the json,

1) It first gets the body as json from the incoming request

```
val jsonBodyOption = body.asJson
```

2) Then the json is validated

```
val qOption = jsonBody.validateOpt[Q] //this uses qReads:Reads available implicitly
```

`qReads` uses `PQReads` to validate the `json`. `PQReads` first calls `validateOpt` passing `pQStructurallyCorrect` which checks the structure. If the structure is correct, then the length of image `List` is checked.